# Trying to save Object in Postgresql database unsuccesfully (no exception)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I try to save object in Postgresql database but unsuccesfully. Application starts normally, no exception is thrown and companiesRepository is not null. The database has been created manually.

This is my **Application.class**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

This is my **Service.class**:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    CompaniesRepository companiesRepository;

    public void start() {
        Companies companies = new Companies();
        companies.setSomeString("some");
        companies.setId(1);

        companiesRepository.save(companies);

        log.info("Companies saved in DB");
}
}
```

This is my **Companies.class**:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Companies {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    Integer id;

    String someString;
}
```

This is my **CompaniesRepository** interface:

```
@Repository
public interface CompaniesRepository extends CrudRepository<Companies, Integer> {

}
```

This is my **Controller.class**:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
private Service service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String start() throws Exception {
        service.start();
        return "App Started";
    }
}
```

The configuration I have in **bootstrap.yaml** file works properly in another project:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: false
    generate-ddl: true
    time_zone: UTC
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update 
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dos?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&serverTimezone=UTC
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: "postgres"
    password: "123"
    initialization-mode: always

hibernate:
   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   jdbc:
     time_zone: UTC
```

I tried to:

> - annottate String and id in **Companies.class** with `@Column(nullable = false)`,
> - changed table name for **Companies.class** with `@Table(name = "some_table")`.
> - add `@Autowired CompaniesRepository repository;` in **Controller.class**

**EDIT:**

Those are the console logs:

```
2020-03-07 15:35:11.620  INFO 2484 --- [           main] com.xtb.tradebot.Application     : Starting Application on MWNB00049 with PID 2484 (C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\trade-bot\trade-bot\target\classes started by Piotr in C:\Users\Piotr\Documents\trade-bot\trade-bot)
2020-03-07 15:35:11.622  INFO 2484 --- [           main] com.xtb.tradebot.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-07 15:35:12.179  INFO 2484 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-07 15:35:12.255  INFO 2484 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-07 15:35:12.638  INFO 2484 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-07 15:35:13.123  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-07 15:35:13.137  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-07 15:35:13.137  INFO 2484 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-03-07 15:35:13.226  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-07 15:35:13.226  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1563 ms
2020-03-07 15:35:13.390  INFO 2484 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-07 15:35:13.673  INFO 2484 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-07 15:35:13.735  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-07 15:35:13.830  INFO 2484 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2020-03-07 15:35:13.995  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-07 15:35:14.131  INFO 2484 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-03-07 15:35:14.731  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-07 15:35:14.735  INFO 2484 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-07 15:35:15.011  WARN 2484 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-07 15:35:15.134  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-07 15:35:15.369  INFO 2484 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-07 15:35:15.371  INFO 2484 --- [           main] com.xtb.tradebot.Application     : Started Application in 4.035 seconds (JVM running for 4.357)
```

Logs after controller "/" endpoint called:

```
2020-03-07 16:28:40.365  INFO 20336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-07 16:28:40.365  INFO 20336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-07 16:28:40.374  INFO 20336 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
```

This is **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xtb</groupId>
    <artifactId>trade-bot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>trade-bot</name>
    <description>trade-bot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: When the boot app starts up, are you sure the connection to the DB is established? Check console for logs. Also, set show-sql: true to see if the sql statment is called.

Comment: @pranshuagarwal I added console logs. With show-sql: true

Comment: I don't any log suggesting `Controller::start` is ever getting called.

Comment: @KedarJoshi I added logs after controller "/" getting called

Comment: which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: also share the pom.xml

Comment: @dassum I use 2.2.4.RELEASE version of Spring Boot. I add pom.xml

Comment: you have configured the H2 database and Postgres database. From the log, I can see it's picking the H2 database. Remove the H2 dependency from pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I deleted h2.database dependency and I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And I added in **bootstrap.yaml**:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

And now it works fine.